# Tapestry file upload and consequent conversion to byte[ ]

Tags: java, apache, byte, tapestry

I am trying to get a file uploaded using the Tapestry upload form in my TML

In .tml file: (this came directly from https://tapestry.apache.org/uploading-files.html)

```
<t:form> <t:errors/> <input t:type="upload" t:id="file" t:value="file" validate="required"/> <br/> 
<input type="submit" value="Upload"/> </t:form>
```

In .java page:

```
@Persist @Property private UploadedFile file;

public void onSuccess() {
        byte[] fileContent = null;
        fileContent = IOUtils.toByteArray(file.getStream());

}
```

I get a null pointer exception when I try to convert the UploadedFile to a byte array. I want to convert it to a byte array so I can store it in the database. I have tried many different methods of converting to byte array or using the file path to access the file, but nothing works. Probably relevant info is that file.getPath() simply returns the name of the file.

I am thinking the InputStream that is generated by file.getstream () is not of the right format.

Answer (score 0):

Debug org.apache.tapestry5.upload.components.Upload processSubmission method. Check what is comming from request.